# API response is giving two responses when only one is requested

Tags: javascript, api

I'm making an API request in JS that is working, but it keeps giving two responses when I'm only expecting one. Here's the code:

```
CallCoinGecko();

function CallCoinGecko() {
  var cgrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url1 = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=';
  var id = 'ethereum';
  var url2 = '&vs_currencies=USD&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true';
  cgrequest.open("GET", url1 + id + url2, true);
  cgrequest.send();
  cgrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (cgrequest.status == 200) {
    var cgresponse = cgrequest.responseText;
    var cgobj = JSON.parse(cgresponse);
    console.log(cgobj);
    var cgprice = (cgobj[id]['usd']);
    console.log(cgprice);
  }}}
```

Here is a console image that shows two responses:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZmun.png)

Any thoughts on this are appreciated thanks

Comment: Sure the function isn't being called twice? Loading same file twice for example, or also calling the function in a load event handler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the api responds twice even though I have called once in JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193844/why-does-the-api-responds-twice-even-though-i-have-called-once-in-javascript-usi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try verifying the value of `readyState` after the request. Example:

`if (cgrequest.status === 200 && cgrequest.readyState === 4)`

The problem is that, as mentioned, the `readyState` can have multiple values - therefore everytime it changes, your code to print the response text will trigger. I'm sure if you looked in the network tab, the API request isn't being carried out two times, only your response text is being printed two times. Checking if it is `4` confirms that the request is done - and should only be carried out once.

My hunch that the API isn't being called two times is due to the fact that the data is *exactly* the same on each `console.log()`.

Good luck :)

Comment: No worries, happy coding :p

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the *readyState* value in your if statement as well.

```js
function CallCoinGecko() {
  var cgrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url1 = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=';
  var id = 'ethereum';
  var url2 = '&vs_currencies=USD&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true';
  cgrequest.open("GET", url1 + id + url2, true);
  cgrequest.onreadystatechange = function(res){
    if (cgrequest.status === 200 && cgrequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var cgresponse = cgrequest.responseText;
        var cgobj = JSON.parse(cgresponse);
        console.log(cgrequest.status, cgobj);
        var cgprice = (cgobj[id]['usd']);
        console.log(cgrequest.status, cgprice);
      }
    };
    cgrequest.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solution also works in addition to the readyState solution